# For loop que no se ejecuta sin dar ninguna error tambien

Tags: vba

He hecho un test con esta Sub pero cuando compilo, no hace nada. Además no dá ninguna error. Entonces no sé como hacer para compilarla.

¿Pueden ayudarme?

```
Public Sub calculerScore()

Dim colonne, ligne, ligne_referencej, colonne_reference, score_reponse As Integer

colonne = 1
ligne = 1
ligne_reference = 1
colonne_reference = 1
For colonne = 1 To colonne = 8
    For ligne = 1 To ligne = 8
        If Cells(ligne, colonne).Value >= Cells(ligne_reference, colonne_reference).Value Then
            Cells(ligne + 10, colonne + 10).Value = 1
        Else
            Cells(ligne + 10, colonne + 10).Value = 0
        End If
        Next ligne
        ligne_reference = ligne_reference + 1
    Next colonne
colonne_reference = colonne_reference + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que tu error esta en las siguientes líneas:

```
For colonne = 1 To colonne = 8
    For ligne = 1 To ligne = 8
```

Después del `To`, cuando pones `colonne = 8` y `ligne = 8`, lo que haces es asignarle el valor a la variable, le estas diciendo al compilador itera esta variable desde que valga 1 hasta que valga 8, o espera dice el compilador aquí ya le estas poniendo el valor de 8 `colonne = 8`, ya vale 8, entonces ya termine el ciclo `For`

Para arreglar tu detalle solo tienes que quitar la asignación, dejar el valor 8 solo.

Cabe mencionar que el código compila **correctametne**, aunque no hace lo que esperas, pero compila porque puedes poner una asignación en esa parte del ciclo `for`, al poner la asignación en `runtime` primero le asigna valor a la variable  después toma la variable como lo que es un valor, con el valor nuevo que ya tiene.

**Ejemplo:**

puedo tener las variables `inicio = 0` y la variable `fin = 10`:

```
for i = inicio To fin
```

que seria equivalente a tener

```
for i= inicio to fin = 10
```

o

```
for i = 0 to 10
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Cambia tu código por este, detalla que cambie las instrucciones `For`:

```
Public Sub calculerScore()

Dim colonne, ligne, ligne_referencej, colonne_reference, score_reponse As Integer

colonne = 1
ligne = 1
ligne_reference = 1
colonne_reference = 1
For colonne = 1 To 8
    For ligne = 1 To 8
        If Cells(ligne, colonne).Value >= Cells(ligne_reference, colonne_reference).Value Then
            Cells(ligne + 10, colonne + 10).Value = 1
        Else
            Cells(ligne + 10, colonne + 10).Value = 0
        End If
        Next ligne
        ligne_reference = ligne_reference + 1
    Next colonne
colonne_reference = colonne_reference + 1
End Sub
```